# Parentheses checker in c using stacks of arrays not producing correct output everytime

Tags: c, stack, stack-overflow, parentheses, brackets

I tried to write a parentheses checker in c using stacks of arrays. The code does not give error messages but sometimes gives the right output and sometimes wrong output.
How can i improve the code or any other suggestions will be very much appreciated. I am a beginner C programmer.
I tried to take the input as a string but could not do it. Any suggestions?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define MAX 25

    int top = -1;
    char stack[MAX];

    void push(char x)
    {
        if(top == MAX - 1){
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
        return;
       }
        stack[++top] = x;
    }

    char pop()
    {
        char popped;
        if(top == -1) {
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        return 0;
        }
    popped = stack[top];
    --top;
    return popped;
    }
        char Top()
    {
        return (stack[top]);

    }
int arePair(char opening,char closing)
{
    if(opening =='(' && closing == ')') return 1;
    else if((opening =='{' && closing == '}')) return 1;
    else if (opening =='[' && closing == ']') return 1;
    return 0;
}

    int paranthesesBalanced(char *exp,int size)
    {
       for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
       {
    if(exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
            push(exp[i]);
        else if (exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}'|| exp[i] == ']') 
        {
            if(top == -1 || !arePair(Top(),exp[i]))
            return 0;
            else
            pop();
        }

           }
            return (top == -1 ? 1:0);

    }


    int main()
    {
        char exp[25];
        int size=0;
        printf("Enter the size of 
    expression\n");
        scanf("%d",&size);
        printf("Enter the expression(Less than 
    25 characters): \n");
        //scanf("%[ˆ\n]%",exp);
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
       {
       scanf("%c",&exp[i]);
       }
        if(paranthesesBalanced(exp,size))
        printf("Balanced!\n");
        else
        printf("Not Balanced!\n");

    }
```

Comment: start with input: **when** does it give you *wrong* output?

Comment: when I enter ```()``` it gives not balanced

Comment: Have you tried using as many print statements at various points to check where it is going wrong or check it using pen and paper going through entire thing - else use a debugger.

Comment: I have not done that. I don't know how to use a debugger. any suggestions?

Comment: @dsaharia If you have GDB installed on your system (check running gdb --version) on your terminal then here is a link to that:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCtY--xRUyI

Else use multiple print statements which will also help you.

Comment: Thank you. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with comments above that you should spend some time to learn how to debug your programs.

The problem with your code lies in the way you read user input. %c matches all characters including new line character. Your code in current form reads newline between size of user data and data itself as first character of the input, so exp[0] == '\n'. There are multiple ways to resolve the issue, like flushing input or uncomment the line you commented (and get rid of superfluous percent sign or switch to some other way of reading your input like using %s instead of using %c in a loop.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal modified version which works correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 25

int top = -1;
char stack[MAX];

void push(char x)
{
    if(top > MAX - 1){              //CHANGED
    printf("Stack Overflow\n");
    return;
   }

    stack[++top] = x;
}

char pop()
{
    char popped;
    if(top == -1) {
    printf("Stack Underflow\n");
    return 0;
    }
popped = stack[top];
--top;
return popped;
}
    char Top()
{
    return (stack[top]);

}
int arePair(char opening,char closing)
{
    if(opening =='(' && closing == ')') return 1;
    else if((opening =='{' && closing == '}')) return 1;
    else if (opening =='[' && closing == ']') return 1;
    return 0;
}

int paranthesesBalanced(char *exp,int size)
{
   for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
        if(exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
            push(exp[i]);
        else if (exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}'|| exp[i] == ']') 
        {
            if(top == -1 || !arePair(Top(),exp[i]))
            return 0;
            else
            pop();
        }
   }
   return (top == -1 ? 1:0);
}


int main()
{
    char exp[25];
    int size=0;
    printf("Enter the size of xpression\n");
    scanf(" %d",&size);
    printf("Enter the expression(Less than 25 characters): \n");
    scanf("%s",exp);     //DELETED FOR LOOP - BETTER USE GETCHAR() RATHER THAN SCANF
    printf("%s\n",exp);
    if(paranthesesBalanced(exp,size))
    printf("Balanced!\n");
    else
    printf("Not Balanced!\n");
}
```

Instead of `scanf` you can go this way as `scanf` doesn't support space i.e. if you enter `hello world` it will only read `hello`. Alternative:

```
 int i,count++;
 while((i=getchar())!=EOF)
 {
     if((i!=\0')&&(count<MAX))
         exp[count++]=i;
     else
         break;
 }
```

In this way you can easily check for length of expression and its limits + it will allow you to enter space.

Comment: printf("%s\n", exp) will cause stack overflow when user input is longer that 25 characters here, "%24s" would be better.

Comment: @robal That's why I have suggested `getchar` to keep the check :)